# cookie setter is set to http:// instead of https://

Tags: php, cookies

i have creating a cookie through this script, it correctly set the cookie according to the way intend but the fact that the cookie setter is set to http:// instead of https://. does anyone of you know how to set it to https

```
   <?php

    header('P3P: CP="NOI DSP COR CURa ADMa DEVa TAIa OUR BUS IND UNI COM NAV INT", policyref="http://ptvdomain.virtualstockexchange.com/w3c/p3p.xml"');
    $id = isset($_REQUEST["id"]) ? floatval($_REQUEST["id"]) : 0;
    $post_id = isset($_REQUEST["cid"]) ? intval($_REQUEST["cid"]) : 0;
    if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'])){
        $urlParts=parse_url($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']);
        if (isset($urlParts['query'])){
            $vars = parse_str($urlParts['query']);
            if (isset($vars['id']) && floatval($vars['id']) > 0 ){
                $id = floatval($vars['id']);
            }
        }
    }         
    if ($id) {
        if ( ! isset($_COOKIE["cookieid"])){
            $cookieid = ($post_id?"$post_id:$id":$id);
            setcookie("cookieid", $cookieid, time() + 60 * 60 * 24 * 365, "/", ".virtualstockexchange.com");
            header('Location: '.Config_File::readConfig('user')->base_url.'/success.php');
        }
    }
```

Comment: A cookie isn't set specifically with http or https.  A cookie is simply a header that the browser looks for and processes.  You can enforce the setting of a cookie only if it's a secure connection, but you can't dictate the protocol of your cookie.

Comment: thanks can you please let me know more about "enforcing the setting of a cookie"

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.setcookie.php - 6th parameter is "secure": secure
Indicates that the cookie should only be transmitted over a secure HTTPS connection from the client. When set to TRUE, the cookie will only be set if a secure connection exists. On the server-side, it's on the programmer to send this kind of cookie only on secure connection (e.g. with respect to $_SERVER["HTTPS"]).